# How to get twitter verify_credintials using C#

Tags: c#, twitter

I executed the steps at this document [implementing sign in twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) and everything done perfectly step by step until the last step where I want to get the user data like (screen-name, id and name) using GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json  but I don't know what is the problem at this code

```
string oauthRequestTokenUrl =
            "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";

        //var oauthCallback = "http://localhost:14993/WebForm1.aspx";
        string oauthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        string oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        string oauthTimestamp =
            Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds,
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        string oauthSignature =
            "oauth_consumer_key=" + UrlEncode(ApiKey) + "&" +
            "oauth_nonce=" + UrlEncode(oauthNonce) + "&" +
            "oauth_signature_method=" + UrlEncode(oauthSignatureMethod) + "&" +
            "oauth_timestamp=" + UrlEncode(oauthTimestamp) + "&" +
            "oauth_token=" + UrlEncode(dic["oauth_token"]) + "&" +
            "oauth_token_secret=" + UrlEncode(dic["oauth_token_secret"]) + "&" +
            "oauth_version=" + UrlEncode("1.0");

        oauthSignature = "GET" + "&" + UrlEncode(oauthRequestTokenUrl) + "&" + UrlEncode(oauthSignature);
        oauthSignature =
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                (new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UrlEncode(ApiSecret) + "&"))).ComputeHash(
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(oauthSignature)));

        string header =
            "OAuth realm=\"Twitter API\"," +
            "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + UrlEncode(ApiKey) + "\"," +
            "oauth_nonce=\"" + UrlEncode(oauthNonce) + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature=\"" + UrlEncode(oauthSignature) + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature_method=\"" + UrlEncode(oauthSignatureMethod) + "\"," +
            "oauth_timestamp=\"" + UrlEncode(oauthTimestamp) + "\"," +
            "oauth_token_secret=\"" + UrlEncode(dic["oauth_token_secret"]) + "\"," +
            "oauth_token=\"" + UrlEncode(dic["oauth_token"]) + "\"," +
            "oauth_version=\"" + UrlEncode("1.0") + "\"";

        var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
                          WebRequest.Create(oauthRequestTokenUrl);
        authRequest.Method = "GET";
        //authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        authRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);

        var authResponse = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = authResponse.GetResponseStream();

        var objectText = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: How you get user profile guys??? I'm depressed.

Comment: The key you're using for HMACSHA1 isn't correct. It should be {consumerApiSecret}&{tokenSecret}. You get the TokenSecret from the "oauth/access_token" step.